# Continuity of magnetic field - infinite wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

Our system is an infinite wire with cylindrical symmetry and radius R, the wire is made of copper.

The current density is given by:

$\frac{p}{R} \hat{z}$, p<R

0, p>R

What is the magnetic field in the whole space?

I solved the problem using the differential ampere law. but I got some constants because of intergration, is the magnetic field must be continous in $p=R$? must it jump by some factor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the integral form of Ampère's law or boundary conditions derived from it you can see that unless there is a surface current density (and there is none according to your problem description) the magnetic field is indeed continuous at the surface.

Comment: there is no surface current density because it is not a perfect conductor? (Copper)

Comment: I don't know about the physics of copper wires. I just took the current density you mentioned as given and it does not contain a surface distribution.
And btw. I guessed that $p$ is the radial distance to the coordinate axis at the center of the wire. Hope that's correct. :)